# Uninstall BIDS 2008

Tags: registry, installation, uninstallation, bids

I had successfully installed BIDS 2008 on my machine. I uninstalled it,  and now need to re-install it.

When going through the setup,  Business Intelligence Development Studio has gray check mark in the Feature Selection screen.  Visual Studio 2008 is not installed on my machine.  I don't see any references to BIDS 2008 in the add/remove programs.  Yet the installer seems to think it's there.

Does anyone know how I can COMPLETELY remove BIDS to re-install it?  Is it a registry file somewhere?   Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My attempts to uninstall Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 from a machine with SQL Server 2008 Express Edition ended with success after following the link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/955404/sql-server-2008-installation-fails-when-you-try-to-install-sql-server

and manually running the command:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=uninstall /FEATURES=BIDS /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS
```

After uninstalling the previous instance of BIDS, the installer allowed me to select/check BIDS and other features.